# Color input box <input type='color'> does not work with input event

Tags: javascript, html

When using the 'input' event with addEventListener() it does not work properly with a color input box.

The HTML is:

```
<input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="colorWell">
 <p>Text to be colored</p>
```

The Javascript is:

```
var colorWell = document.getElementById('colorWell');
colorWell.addEventListener("input", updateFirst, false);

function updateFirst(event) {
  var p = document.querySelector("p");

  if (p) {
    p.style.color = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

What should happen is that when a color in the color box is clicked, the 'input' event listener should fire, causing the text in `<p>` tag to color. This should all happen before the color box OK button is clicked.

This does not happen - the coloring only occurs after the OK button is clicked.

I'm using Chrome. Is this a Chrome problem? If so, is there a work around?

Comment: @dcr test thats all

Answer (score 0):

```js
var colorWell = document.getElementById('colorWell');
colorWell.addEventListener("input", updateFirst, false);

function updateFirst(event) {
  var p = document.querySelector("p");

  if (p) {
    p.style.color = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="colorWell">
 <p>Text to be colored</p>
```

Comment: How as does this answer the question at all? I know it was a simple issue, but you have only copied the code and still not corrected the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add `...addEventListener("click",...` above (or below) your `"input"` one.

Full sample below:

```js
var colorWell = document.getElementById('colorWell');
colorWell.addEventListener("click", updateFirst, false);
colorWell.addEventListener("input", updateFirst, false);

function updateFirst(event) {
  var p = document.querySelector("p");

  if (p) {
    p.style.color = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="colorWell">
 <p>Text to be colored</p>
```

Comment: Tried replacing 'input' with 'click' but it did not work! Are you aware of any problems with Chrome and the color box?

Comment: @havelly - The sample in the answer is working for Chrome and Firefox on Linux for me. I'm unable to test on other platforms atm.

Comment: Am using Chrome on the golden oldie Windows XP. Could this be the issue?

Comment: I can not answer if Windows XP is the issue or not. [Extended support for Windows XP ended on April 8, 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP) - Highly suggest at least looking at Linux as an option that is both current and safe.

Comment: @havelly - I tried the mdn docs page that it looks like you got your code from with Win10 - works as you want in latest FF, but doesn't change the color until OK is clicked in latest Chrome

Comment: @havelly : You could try adding a `select` and/or `change` listener the same as the `click` one in the answer sample code. Leave the `click` one as well as that works for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below -

```
    <html>
    <body onLoad="startup()">
    <script language="javascript" >

     function startup()
     {
       colorWell = document.querySelector("#colorWell");

       colorWell.addEventListener("input", updateFirst,false); 
       colorWell.select();
    }




    function updateFirst(event)
    {
       var colorWell = document.getElementById('colorWell');
       var p = document.querySelector("p");

      if (p)
       {

          p.style.color = event.target.value;
       }
   }


   </script>
   <input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="colorWell" onSelect='alert("X")'>
   <p>Text to be colored</p>


   <input class="Randombutton" style="float: left;" type="button" value="Randomize" 
    onclick="randomImg()">

    <div id="quote">

   </div>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```